# My eventlistener that works just fine in my html file doesnt work in my elementor file

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, addeventlistener, elementor

I had problems with my navbar so i recreated my wordpress nav bar but when I tried to insert it into elementor it doesnt work. I checked all the classes and they are they same and when i console log than it works fine until I use an eventlistener.

The function reveals a Menu when you hover over certain menu points and it stays revealed until i hover over the next menupoint with a submenu.

Thanks in advance.

var fadeIn = [
        { opacity: '0'},
        { top: '1'}
    ];

    var fadeInDuration = {
        duration: 300,
        iterations: 1
    };

    var fadeOut = [
        { top: '0'},
        { top: '-100vh'}
    ];

    var fadeOutDuration = {
        duration: 100,
        iterations: 1
    };
    
        var arbeitenSubMenu = document.querySelector('.arbeiten .sub-menu');
        var teamSubMenu = document.querySelector('.team .sub-menu');
        var arbeiten = document.querySelector('.arbeiten');
        var team = document.querySelector('.team');
        var i = 0;
        var u = 0;
    
        console.log('hello');

        arbeiten.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
            console.log('mouseenter');
            i = i + 1;
            u = 0;
            if ( i === 1 ){
                arbeitenSubMenu.classList.add('active-sub-menu');
                arbeitenSubMenu.animate(fadeIn, fadeInDuration);
                teamSubMenu.classList.remove('active-sub-menu');

                setTimeout(() => {
                    document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#fff'; 
                }, "300");
            }
        })   

        team.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
            u = u + 1;
            i = 0;
            if ( u === 1 ){
                console.log('mouseenter team');
                    teamSubMenu.classList.add('active-sub-menu');
                    teamSubMenu.animate(fadeIn, fadeInDuration);
                    arbeitenSubMenu.classList.remove('active-sub-menu');
                    document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
            }
        })

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.